# Error when drawing a UIBezierPath. No current point

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a `UIBezierPath` like this:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
[path closePath];
```

The problem is that when I try to draw my `UIBezierPath`, it does not appear and I get an error:

```
<Error>: void CGPathCloseSubpath(CGMutablePathRef): no current point.
```

My drawing code is very basic:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[myPath stroke];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is clear. One line of code was missing when I was creating my `UIBezierPath`:

```
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

I added it and everything worked like a charm.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
[path closePath]
```

It is interesting that the error happened when I was trying to draw the line and not before - when I created it.

Comment: I'm using a simple UIBezierPath to create a SceneKit SCNShape. I get the same warning about no current point, but when I add in the move to (0,0), the shape no longer appears in my SceneKit scene. Very odd.